# ZF2 - Get ServiceManager from layout

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

In my Application layout i have one  segment which represent ADMIN PANEL. I render that segment by the partial('admin_panel.phtml'); ?> view helper.

Now, I want to render 'admin_panel.phtml' if a user have 'admin' role and not if it doesn't. My idea was to check users role and based on that render admin panel or not.

I have service registered with ServiceManager as invokable, which return current users role, but how to get ServiceManager from layout?! How to call my service to check users role?

Comment: Ok i've solved it. In bootstrap of module.php i have checked for user role by my service, then I set that result in a viewModel variable. So I didnt have to call ServiceManager from layout. But I'm still interested is it possilbe?

Comment: Sure its possible to call the Servicemanager instance from layout, if you pass it as viewModel parameter like you did :D ..this is the correct solid MVC pattern way of doing it. 
A "direct" association of the ServiceManager within the layout files would breach the MVC pattern ;-)